# matching network BLE antenna

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

Hi I'm using a BLE module connected to a chip antenna, the antenna manufacture establish the path width is .4mm, if I need to match the network to 50ohm how can I do it? the system has a pi-match C1=0.8pF L=3.9nH and C2 is 0.8pF how can I make sure it match to 50 ohm?

Comment: I wonder if you question would get better response over on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Your network contain 2 parts:

- Antenna + pi-match
- BLE module

You need to make sure both 2 part meet the requirement 50 ohm itself so you have to isolate 2 part.

(You can use the knife to remove a small path in the transmission line)

After isolation, use a 50ohm cable, solder one side of cable to each part, other side to the Vector network analyzer.

If the S-parameter you got is <-8dB in your frequency range => You got 50 ohm matching.
(Try change value of your pi to got value close to 50ohm)